# Parameters empty using JSF/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have a mistake when i try to pass an argument from JSF to Javascript, my parameters are empty.

JSF code :

```
<h:commandButton immediate="true" value="#{bundle.hello}" 
                            onclick="return test('#{myBean.parameter1}', '#{myBean.parameter2}');"/>
```

Javascript code :

```
function test(parameter, parameter2){
    html2canvas($('#body'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var newImg = window.open(img);
            newImg.document.write("<title>" + parameter+ " - " + parameter2+ "</title>");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

I find something strange, if i remove the "return false" in my function, the parameters are ok. Unfortunately, i need the "return false" for other reasons.

Could you explain me how i must fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: How does the generated HTML output of the command button look like?

Comment: If i keep the return false, the generated HTML output looks like : <input type="submit" name="testForm:j_idt589" value="Print" onclick="return test('','');">

If i remove the return false :

Comment: So, those parameters are not set by you, but by the enduser in input fields of the same form?

Comment: If i remove the return false, the generated html output is
    <input type="submit" name="testForm:j_idt589" value="Print" onclick="test('Hello', '123456');">

Comment: This is surely a misinterpretation caused by a misconception of how basic web stuff works and you're looking at the generated HTML output **after** you clicked the button. You should be looking at the generated HTML output **before** you click the button because that's then the state as it was during the click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EL (those `#{}` things) runs during generating HTML output, not during executing JavaScript code. Do a rightclick and *View Source* in webbrowser. You'll see

```
onclick="return test('', '');"
```

When the onclick is fired, the `test()` function is obviously called with empty parameters. I'm absolutely not seeing how changing the function's return value to `true` fixes this problem. Most likely you're misidentifying the problem and the problem is only "fixed" when the button is pressed twice instead of once.

You need to solve this differently. One way would be to let JS grab the HTML input element's value directly. E.g.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputText id="input1" ... />
    <h:inputText id="input2" ... />
    <h:commandButton ... onclick="test(); return false;" />
</h:form>
```

with

```
function test() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById("form:input1").value;
    var input2 = document.getElementById("form:input2").value;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you BalusC :) It's working. I didn't think the problem was the EL in the HTML.

Comment: I have another problem, i have edit my first post. Could you read it please? Thank you.

Comment: If you have a new question, just ask a new question. Do not reuse/chameleonize existing questions for new and completely unrelated questions/problems.